# Handle exceptions in JSF (view) and save this exception message

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, oracle-adf

I have two Classes that extend from `ExceptionHandlerWrapper` & `ExceptionHandlerFactory`
for catching any exceptions that occur in the view layer 
and navigate to error page and show this error. 
So I need store or save this exceptions somewhere 
but I can`t get this exception message.
I tried to get this message in session but I need another way to save this message with out ViewScope and PageFlowScope and RequestScope since the latter ones return 'null'

```
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandler;
import javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory;

public class CustomExceptionHandlerFactory extends ExceptionHandlerFactory {

    private ExceptionHandlerFactory parent;

    public CustomExceptionHandlerFactory(ExceptionHandlerFactory parent) {
      this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getExceptionHandler() {
      ExceptionHandler result = new CustomExceptionHandler(parent.getExceptionHandler());
      return result;
    }
 }
```

---

```
  public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ExceptionHandlerWrapper {
    private ExceptionHandler wrapped;


    public CustomExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public ExceptionHandler getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
        Iterator iterator = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            ExceptionQueuedEvent event = (ExceptionQueuedEvent) iterator.next();
            ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();


            Throwable throwable = context.getException();
            FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();


            // Map<String, Object> sessionMap = fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
             NavigationHandler navigator = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();


            AdfFacesContext adfc = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

          Map<String,Object> valueViewScope =   adfc.getViewScope();


            try {
                //  Flash flash = fc.getExternalContext().getFlash();
                // Put the exception in the flash scope to be displayed in the error
                // page if necessary ...
                //  flash.put("errorDetails", throwable.getMessage());

                ADFContext.getCurrent().getSessionScope().put("errorDetails", throwable.getMessage());

                valueViewScope.put("errorDetails", throwable.getMessage());

                System.out.println("the error is put in the Session: " + throwable.getMessage());

                //NavigationHandler navigationHandler = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
                navigator.handleNavigation(fc, null, "ErrorPage?faces-redirect=true");
                // navigationHandler.handleNavigation(fc, null, "ErrorPage?faces-redirect=true");

                fc.renderResponse();
            } finally {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        // Let the parent handle the rest
        getWrapped().handle();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by the last added sentence? _"Because When I need return this scope in any where returns null."_

Comment: when i get Session Scope or Request  , ViewScope , PageFlowScope
In Bean Return Null But , In  Error Page  
            <af:outputText id="ot1" value="#{sessionScope['errorDetails']}"/>

get Value In Session Scope 
But I Need Another Way To Pass This Value With Exception Message

Comment: Can you correct those sentences? it's really hard to understand what you mean

Comment: Well, I could sort of but your explanation in your comment contains a contradiction. You summarize all scopes **including** session scope now and say they return null but later on you state you get the value in session scope.

Comment: Yes Your Explanation is correct , My Issue I need Another Way Without SessionScope
, and another Scopes like view and request and pageFlow  return null